# Unauthorized modifications on SQLite files

Tags: sqlite

My application will export and import data from SQLite db file. Is there any way to identify that before importing, that SQLite db file have been accessed and modified by unauthroized(other) users.

Application development using C++.

Is there any way to protect that db file like using password.

Comment: No, not as a feature of sqlite.  You need to research features of your operating system and file system to learn how to secure your files.  You may be able to use system auditing features to log access and file changes.  Set file permissions using standard security features of the operating system and/or network.

Answer (score 0):

No, not as a feature of sqlite.  A sqlite database is just a file that is accessed by software just like any other file.  It is not a server application that has any built-in security features to accomplish what you request.  There is no code that you can write in your C++ application that will prevent other software from accessing the sqlite database file(s) (unless that code implements OS security features, but once again that is not specific to sqlite).

You need to research features of your network, operating system and file system to learn how to secure your files. You may be able to use system auditing features to log access and file changes. Research how to set file permissions using standard security features of the operating system and/or network.